# Trying to annotate classes to represent a json string with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an JSON structure from an external source and have some difficulty trying to build a class structure that can be used for deserialization. I have registered that each member of the json array has a name for the array item (oneDevice) - first time i see this

```
{
  "pushResponse" : [
    {
      "oneDevice" : {
        "status" : "Error 0",
        "token" : "7676jbhjh",
        "type" : "gcm"
      }
    },
    {
      "oneDevice" : {
        "status" : "Error 0",
        "token" : "asdasf66a",
        "type" : "gcm"
      }
    }
]}
```

I have tried to create the following class structure but get an error message when running the code:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true )
public class PushOkResponse {

  @JsonProperty("pushResponse")
  @XmlElement(required = true)
  protected PushResponseType pushResponse;
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = false )
public class PushResponseType {

  @JsonProperty( "oneDevice" )
  protected List<OneDeviceType> oneDevice;
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = false )
public class OneDeviceType {

  @XmlElement( required = true )
  @JsonProperty( "status" )
  protected String status;

  @XmlElement( required = true )
  @JsonProperty( "token" )
  private String token;

  @XmlElement( required = true )
  @JsonProperty( "type" )
  private String type;
}


PushOkResponse pushOkResponse = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, PushOkResponse.class);
```

fails with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of (packageName ommitted)...PushResponseType out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: {   "pushResponse" : [      {         "oneDevice" : {            "status" : "Error 0",            "token" : "7676jbhjh",            "type" : "gcm"         }      }   ]}; line: 1, column: 22] (through reference chain: (packageName ommitted)...PushOkResponse["pushResponse"])

Answer (score 0):

Reading the following POST [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154631/json-mapping-exception-can-not-deserialize-instance-out-of-start-array-token) i finally got this to work only short time after posting the question.

If I instead use List in the PushOkResponse class, and drop the List for the OneDeviceType in the PushResponseType class everything worked fine. Like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true )
public class StrettoOkResponse extends StrettoResponse {

  @JsonProperty("pushResponse")
  @XmlElement(required = true)
  protected List<PushResponseType> pushResponse;
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = false )
public class PushResponseType {

  @JsonProperty( "oneDevice" )
  protected OneDeviceType oneDevice;
}
```