# Error while declaring the word `public` as a String variable intellij

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

How can I configure the IntelliJ IDE to not be so strict in the following class member fields:

```
String public;
String metaClass;
```

Currently, it shows an error about the `String public` member.

This is the naming I want, because of a JSON contract I must conform to.

Comment: You shouldn't link external images that could get lost

Comment: I edited the question content to better reflect the essence of the issue. In the future, try to be as concrete as possible to the problem and your reasoning.

Comment: As a hint, try to rename the problematic member to some other acceptable by the compiler name. You can use an annotation to tell your JSON serialization framework what is the field name in the JSON format, so you do not need to have the exact same naming in the respective Java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking why this code ...

```
String public
```

... does not compile.

Or to put it another way: "why does IntelliJ not allow this code?".

The word `public` is not a valid variable name in Java so no compiler (whether hosted by IntelliJ or by anything else) will not allow that code.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> The rules and conventions for naming your variables can be summarized as follows:
>   ...
>   Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or reserved word.

Here's the full list of [keywords and reserved words](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

In your question you wrote "This is i want format, because of the json objects" by which I think you mean that you have JSON which contains an attribute named ""public" and you want to map that to a Java class having an attribute named "public". If so, then you'll need to transform the JSON when deserilaising into your Java class. This is likely to be supported by whatever JSON library you are using. For example, Jackson provides the `@JsonProperty` and `@JsonAlias` annotations for this ... allowing this JSON: `{"public": "true"}` to be deserialised into a class with this member: `@JsonAlias({ "public" }) public String publicScope`.

Comment: Sorry for the grammar buddy, but it is the exact question that you've said in this comment. Thanks! How about the JSON Arrays, i had a problem on deserializing this stuffs, I'm using Jackson Json. I have always an error which means "START_OF_ARRAY" what will i gonna do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Re your follow up question, I think that might already have an answer SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154631/json-mapping-exception-can-not-deserialize-instance-out-of-start-array-token) perhaps?). If you cannot find an existing answer on SO then I think you should raise a new question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the very least you should include example JSON, your model class and your deserialisation code ... it's very difficult to diagnose the issue without those details.